# Authorization in ASP.NET Core, how do I provide tenancy id before DbContext initiates

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

The authorization of my application is based on "Organization", a user belongs to an organization (some thing like multi tenancy?), so a user will have its `UserId` and `OrganizationId`. The `UserId` is provided in the JWT token, but the `OrganizationId` has to be acquired from the database according to the `UserId`.

I have an `ICurrentUserService` which extracts `UserId` and `OrganizationId` from the `HttpContext`:

```cs
public class CurrentUserService : ICurrentUserService
{
    public string UserId {get; set;}
    public string OrganizationId {get; set;}

    public CurrentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        UserId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(nameof(UserId));
        OrganizationId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User.FindFirstValue(nameof(OrganizationId));
    }
}
```

`DbContext` relies on `ICurrentUserService` for `UserId` and `OrganizationId`, it uses the `OrganizationId` for a global query filter:

```cs
public class DbContext
{
    DbContext(ICurrentUserService _currentUserService)
    {
        _organizationId = _currentUserService.OrganizationId;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        // use OrganizationId for query filter
        builder.Entity<Device>().HasQueryFilter(x => x.OrganizationId == _organizationId);
    }
}
```

Since I don't have the `OrganizationId` in the JWT token, I have a `PermissionsMiddleware` to query the `OrganizationId` and then adds it as a `ClaimsIdentity` to the `HttpContext`'s `ClaimsPrincipal`:

```cs
public class PermissionsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
{
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, DbContext db)
    {
        string uId = context.User.FindFirst("UserId")?.Value;
        MyUser user = await db.Set<MyUser>().FindAsync(uId);
        string orgId = user.OrganizationId;
        var accountClaims = new List<Claim>()
                                {
                                    new Claim("OrganizationId", orgId)
                                }
        var orgIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity("OrganizationPermission", "name", "role");
        orgIdentity.AddClaims(claimPermissions);

        context.User.AddIdentity(orgIdentity);
    }
}
```

As you might see, the `PermissionsMiddleware` depends on the `DbContext`, which depends on `ICurrentUserService`, which depends on `PermissionsMiddleware` for providing the `OrganizationId`!

When a request comes in, a `PermissionsMiddleware` is invoked, which requires `DbContext`. So `DbContext` is initiated before `PermissionsMiddleware`, without knowing the `OrganizationId`, since `DbContext` is a scope-dependency, it will keep that way.

How can I fix this problem? I can think of making `DbContext` and `ICurrentUserService` into transient dependencies, but that could affect the performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply set up a different DbContext that does not depend on the OrganizationId. This is the recommended approach when you have too many concerns going into a single DbContext.

```cs
public class DbContextMiddleware
{
   // ...
}
```

Then change the dependency in the middleware.

```cs
public class PermissionsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
{
    public async Task InvokeAsync(
    HttpContext context, DbContextMiddleware db)
   {
       // ..
   }
}
```